How to import a monorepo package into an app with hot-reload?
I have a turborepo monorepo with the following structure:
- apps
  - a
- packages
  - x

The packages/x folder exports some components in a index.tsx file.
The apps/a folder needs to import these components from a single entry point:
import { Foo } from "@packages/x"

To do this, apps/a has the following line in its package.json:
 "@packages/x": "*",

It worked when I was pre-building packages/x in a dist folder. But I need to have the hot-reload when using apps/a. Also, @packages/x has a lot of internal alias paths.
How can I import the components of packages/x's index.tsx from any app in my monorepo while having the hot-reload? All the apps are written in NextJS.
